# Ruby error: "Symbol as array index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing a spec for the `create` method of a controller :

```
describe "POST create" do

    it "should create an adtag with valid params" do
      campaign = Campaign.make

      campaign_attributes = Hash.new
      campaign_attributes[:adtag_attributes] = Hash.new
      campaign_attributes[:adtag_attributes][:code] = "<h1>Sample code</h1>"

      post 'create', { :id => campaign.id, :campaign => campaign_attributes }
    end

end
```

But when I run it, I get the error `"Symbol as array index"` in the controller, when it tries to process this code :

```
params[:campaign][:adtag_attributes].each_with_index do |attributes,index|
  # some code
end
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

EDIT 1:

I haven't written the controller, but it works with manual testing.
The view that calls my controller has this code:

```
fields_for 'campaign[adtag_attributes][]', adtag do |adtag_form|
```

Maybe my spec isn't good ?

EDIT 2:

Problem resolved thanks to Rishav's answer. I didn't understand that in the view, `campaign[adtag_attributes][]` means that `campaign[adtag_attributes]` is an Array.

So I just replaced

```
campaign_attributes = Hash.new
campaign_attributes[:adtag_attributes] = Hash.new
campaign_attributes[:adtag_attributes][:code] = "<h1>Sample code</h1>"
```

by

```
campaign_attributes = Hash.new
campaign_attributes[:adtag_attributes] = Array.new
campaign_attributes[:adtag_attributes] << { :code => "<h1>Sample code</h1>" }
```

and it worked out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

params[:campaign][:adtag_attributes] is a hash not an array, so when it runs "each_with_index" method on the hash it sees ":code" symbol as the index and throws that error.

You can just do this

```
 params[:campaign][:adtag_attributes].each do |key,value|
    #some code
 end
```

just change to following in the test

`params[:campaign][:adtag_attributes]  = [] 

  params[:campaign][:adtag_attributes]  << somedata`

hopefully this works

Comment: I haven't written the controller, but it works with manual testing. See my post edit for more details.